Layout of a a css grid area does not expand and does not show a scrollbar
I have the following html and css file. What I want to achieve is a standard layout with header and footer and menubar with css grid. This seems to work great.
Now I want to layout the content area and there also define a css grid but it has two problems.
If the subcontent (the table) only has few entries then it does not stretch over the rest of the available space. And if it has too many entries and would overflow it does not show the scrollbar.
I thougt all I would need is a
align-self: stretch;
overflow-y: auto;

but they don't seem to have any effect.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  
    <div class="container">
    
      <div class="menu">
        menu
      </div>
    
      <div class="header">
        header
      </div>
      
      <div class="content">

        <div class="subcontainer">
        
          <div class="subheader">
            subheader
          </div>
          
          <div class="subcontent">
            <table>
              <tr><td>subcontent</td></tr>
              <tr><td>subcontent</td></tr>
              <tr><td>subcontent</td></tr>
              <tr><td>subcontent</td></tr>
              <tr><td>subcontent</td></tr>
              <tr><td>subcontent</td></tr>
              <tr><td>subcontent</td></tr>
              <tr><td>subcontent</td></tr>
              <tr><td>subcontent</td></tr>
              <tr><td>subcontent</td></tr>
              <tr><td>subcontent</td></tr>
              <tr><td>subcontent</td></tr>
              <tr><td>subcontent</td></tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          
          <div class="subfooter">
            subfooter
          </div>
          
        </div>  
        
      </div>
      
      <div class="footer">
        footer
      </div>
      
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>

and the css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template:
    [row1-start] "header header" min-content [row1-end]
    [row2-start] "menu content" 1fr [row2-end]
    [row3-start] "footer footer" min-content [row3-end]
    / 100px auto;
}

.menu {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-area: menu;
}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  grid-area: header;
}

.content {
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-area: content;
}

.footer {
  background-color: green;
  grid-area: footer;
}


.subcontainer {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template:
    [row1-start] "subheader" min-content [row1-end]
    [row2-start] "subcontent" 1fr [row2-end]
    [row3-start] "subfooter" min-content [row3-end]
    / auto;
}

.subheader {
  background-color: purple;
  grid-area: subheader;
}

.subcontent {
  background-color: brown;
  grid-area: subcontent;
  align-self: stretch;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.subfooter {
  background-color: pink;
  grid-area: subfooter;
}

This illustrates the first problem, that the subcontent does not get stretched.

And this is with a long table which should stay inside its bounds and display a scrollbar instead

And this is how it should look ideally in the overflow case. The scrollbar is only inside the subcontent area.


Ok my first problem was a missing "height: 100%" in the subcontainer. With that it stretches as I want and I actually can remove the "align-self: stretch" but my second problem still exists.



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0;
      }

      .container {
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: lightblue;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      .menu {
        background-color: blue;
        height: 100%;
      }
      .bodycontainer {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
      .header {
        background-color: red;
        grid-area: header;
      }

      .content {
        background-color: yellow;
      }

      .footer {
        background-color: green;
        grid-area: footer;
      }

      .subcontainer {
        background-color: lightblue;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100%;
      }

      .subheader {
        background-color: purple;
        grid-area: subheader;
        height: 10%;
      }

      .subcontent {
        background-color: brown;
        overflow-y: auto;
      }

      .subfooter {
        background-color: pink;
        grid-area: subfooter;
        height: 10%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="header">header</div>
      <div class="bodycontainer">
        <div class="menu">menu</div>

        <div class="subcontainer">
          <div class="subheader">subheader</div>

          <div class="subcontent">
            <table>
              <tr>
                <td>subcontent</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>subcontent</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>subcontent</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>subcontent</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>subcontent</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>subcontent</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>subcontent</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>subcontent</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>subcontent</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>subcontent</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>subcontent</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>subcontent</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>subcontent</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>subcontent</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>subcontent</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>subcontent</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>subcontent</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>subcontent</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>subcontent</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>subcontent</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>subcontent</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>subcontent</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>subcontent</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>subcontent</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>

          <div class="subfooter">subfooter</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">footer</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



I just run your code and I did not see the first problem you mentioned
The second problem is solved in the above code provided
To make the scroll bar appear inside the .subcontent div when there are more table entries, you can set a specific height for the .subcontent div and then use the overflow-y: auto; CSS property to enable vertical scrolling. This will create a scrollable area inside the .subcontent div when its content exceeds the specified height. Adjust the height value to fit your design requirements.

Interesrting that you could not see my first problem. For me I can solve it if I set "height: 100%" on the subcontainer.

But my second problem is not solved in your example. I can get the scrollbars with a fixed height of the subcontent but now I see the yellow part shining through. What I want is that the subcontent uses all the remaining space. That's why I set it to 1fr in the grid.

You are not clarifying your problem
first you want was the scroll bar inside the div
tell me what remaining space means
and i did not get whether you want yellow part or not
make a screenshot of what you want with clear instructions
I will try to solve that

Sorry for my ambiguity. I have this content area in my first grid where I add a subcontainer which I want to divide again into a subheader, subcontent and subfooter. The subheader should always be on the top of the content area and the subfooter on the bottom. The subcontent should use up all remaining space but never bigger and instead overflow into a scrollbar.
I will try to add a picture for this.

Okay Okay I got it
let me explain this
you want the sub header and sub footer has fixed height the remaining height must be taken by the sub content
is that what you want ?

Yes exactly. Ideally I would keep the sub header and sub footer with min-content. But fixed would be ok too if this is necessary. But the sub content height of course depends on the users screen size.

Now I have edited the answer
check this out and tell me whether you want this layout or there are still any changes

Hmm is there no solution with CSS grid?

flex box is easy to understand and use
I use grid when I have layout in columns but here we are mostly dealing in rows
This is also achievable through grid
let me try again using grid

Yes that would be great!

Everything is almost working. It remains to install  .content { display: grid; minimum height: 0; }, and .subcontainer { min-height: 0; }.
min-height: 0 is required to shrinking.


body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template:
    "header header" min-content 
    "menu content" 1fr
    "footer footer" min-content
    / 100px auto;
}

.menu {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-area: menu;
}

.header {
  background-color: red;
  grid-area: header;
}

.content {
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-area: content;
  display: grid;
  min-height: 0;
}

.footer {
  background-color: green;
  grid-area: footer;
}


.subcontainer {
  background-color: lightblue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template:
    "subheader" min-content
    "subcontent" 1fr
    "subfooter" min-content;
  min-height: 0;
}

.subheader {
  background-color: purple;
  grid-area: subheader;
}

.subcontent {
  background-color: brown;
  grid-area: subcontent;
  align-self: stretch;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.subfooter {
  background-color: pink;
  grid-area: subfooter;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="menu">
    menu
  </div>
  <div class="header">
    header
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="subcontainer">
      <div class="subheader">
        subheader
      </div>
      <div class="subcontent">
        <table>
          <tr><td>subcontent</td></tr>
          <tr><td>subcontent</td></tr>
          <tr><td>subcontent</td></tr>
          <tr><td>subcontent</td></tr>
          <tr><td>subcontent</td></tr>
          <tr><td>subcontent</td></tr>
          <tr><td>subcontent</td></tr>
          <tr><td>subcontent</td></tr>
          <tr><td>subcontent</td></tr>
          <tr><td>subcontent</td></tr>
          <tr><td>subcontent</td></tr>
          <tr><td>subcontent</td></tr>
          <tr><td>subcontent</td></tr>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="subfooter">
        subfooter
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    footer
  </div>
</div>




I now did a lot more research and at least think I understood what is going on.
From that it seems that another solution is actually preferred. I you set minmax(0, 1fr) on the container then everything magically works.
As this question seems to be now marked as a duplicate I can't add another answer with this solution.
